# Java Wild card to search for directory

Tags: java, path, wildcard

I need to search for a folder which changes for different environments. Although the file name remains constant , the folder name is changed.

In the below screenshot , branch-name changes for the environment; Config and the log file remains the same.

[image]

I want to use wild card to search for the config inside the branch-name folder. I used the following , but that doesnt seem to work and returns an error message saying path not found.

`String LOCAL_DIR = "*/config/";`

What should be done in order to search for the branch-name folder without passing it as the name is changed across various environments ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to use wildcards, you would need to implement wildcards by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine using a library, we can do a recursive search in a root folder that you can mention and achieve this by searching for files having .log as extension

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Sample Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //mention the file suffix
        String[] SUFFIX = {"log"};
        
        //mention your root directory here to do a recursive search
        String root_dir = "C:\\work";
        
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(root_dir), SUFFIX, true);
        
        for(File file: files) {
            if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains("/config/") //this will be good for unix/linux
                        || file.getAbsolutePath().contains("\\config\\") //this will be good for windows
                    ) {
                //this is your required file meeting all the criteria
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for the reply. 
I feel this is a bit extensive given the current scenario. I need to pick a test file during a test run from the folder and hence looking for a simple solution. Wild card although dint help me.